# Php Doctrine: how to avoid full qualified entity name in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

I would like to know if it is possible to avoid the full qualified entity name in a DQL.
For example, I have an Entity **User** with namespace **App\Entity**

instead of using:

```
SELECT a FROM App\Entity\User a
```

I would like to use:

```
SELECT a FROM User a
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not use ORM Mapping and in addition querybuilder?

Comment: The problem is that it is a legacy project and my task is add namespace in all php classes. And there are many DQL queries already there. :(. If I don't find a solution related to namespaces in DQL, I'll have to chane one by one :(